# Complex LINQ query from SQL query

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-entities

I have an SQL query :

```
 SELECT Sum(ABS([Minimum Installment])) AS SumOfMonthlyPayments FROM tblAccount 
        INNER JOIN tblAccountOwner ON tblAccount.[Creditor Registry ID] = tblAccountOwner.
        [Creditor Registry ID] AND tblAccount.[Account No] = tblAccountOwner.[Account No] 
        WHERE (tblAccountOwner.[Account Owner Registry ID] = 731752693037116688) 
        AND (tblAccount.[Account Type] NOT IN ('CA00', 'CA01', 'CA03', 'CA04', 'CA02', 'PA00', 'PA01', 'PA02', 'PA03', 'PA04')) 
        AND (DATEDIFF(mm, tblAccount.[State Change Date], GETDATE()) <= 
        6 OR tblAccount.[State Change Date] IS NULL)
        AND (tblAccount.[Account Status ID] <> 999)
        AND ((tblAccount.[Account Type] NOT IN ('CL01','PL01','CL10','
        CL11','PL10','PL11','OD','CL00','PL00','CL03','CL20','CL30','CL31','CL32',
        'CL33','CL34','CL35','CL69','CL90','ML00','PL03','PL20','PL30','PL31','PL33',
        'CA00', 'CA01', 'CA03', 'CA04', 'CA02', 'PA00', 'PA01', 'PA02', 'PA03', 'PA04',
        'PL34','PL35','PL40','PL90')) 
        AND NOT CONTAINS(tblAccount.[Account Type], 'Overdra') 
        OR NOT CONTAINS(tblAccount.[Account Type], 'Mortgage') 
        OR NOT CONTAINS(tblAccount.[Account Type],'Revolv') 
        OR NOT CONTAINS(tblAccount.[Account Type],'*Credit*Card*'))
```

I have translated it to LINQ:

```
var excludeTypes = new[]
               {
                  "CA00", "CA01", "CA03", "CA04", "CA02",
                    "PA00", "PA01", "PA02", "PA03", "PA04"      
               };

            var maxStateChangeMonth = 4;
            var excludeStatusId = 999;
            var includOtherPayments = new[] {
                        "CL01","PL01","CL10",
                        "CL11","PL10","PL11","OD","CL00","PL00","CL03","CL20","CL30",
                        "CL31","CL32,CL33","CL34","CL35","CL69","CL90","ML00","PL03",
                        "PL20","PL30","PL31","PL33,CA00", "CA01", "CA03", "CA04","CA02",
                        "PA00", "PA01", "PA02", "PA03", "PA04,PL34","PL35","PL40","PL90" 
                    };

            var sum = (
               from account in context.Accounts
               from owner in account.AccountOwners
               where owner.AccountOwnerRegistryId == ownerRegistryId
               where !excludeTypes.Contains(account.AccountType)
               where account.StateChangeDate == null
               ||
                   EntityFunctions.DiffMonths(account.StateChangeDate, DateTime.Now)
                       <= maxStateChangeMonth
               where includOtherPayments.Contains(account.AccountType) ||
                       !account.AccountType.Contains("Overdra") || !account.AccountType.Contains("Mortgage")
                       || !account.AccountType.Contains("Revolv") || !account.AccountType.Contains("*Credit*Card*")
               where account.AccountStatusId != excludeStatusId
               select (decimal?)account.MinimumInstallment).ToList()
               .Sum(minimumInstallment => Math.Abs((decimal)(minimumInstallment)));

            return sum;
```

but SQL is returning 0 where as LINq is returning 23456. I know the issue is with paranthesis in LINQ or order of where statements. Please suggest me solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try putting your LINQ query into [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/).  It's a useful free tool that'll show you the raw SQL generated by your LINQ query to help you debug it.  It'll work with both LINQ-to-SQL and Entity Framework queries.

Comment: I used LINQPAD but I can't use it with this query because I am using entites instead of tablename in this query.

Comment: only issue is paranthesis or order of where statements.

Answer (score 0):

From the first look main difference is:
 - FTS function `contains` in SQL query
 - Method `Contains` in LINQ query (which is translated into `like`, not into FTS call)

If you want to use FTS - you should use table valued functions (TVF) or stored procedures (SP). There are some other options (for example, ExecuteQuery), but I don't find them convenient.